# Converting Excel times to POSIXct in r

Tags: r, posixct, chron

I'm using an Excel dataset where the time values, MM:SS, come in numeric values that I need to convert to POSIXct in r and then make calculations.

Below is sample data of what I have and I need to get

```
dfOrig <- data.frame(StandarTime =  c(615,735,615 ),
                 AchievedTime =  c(794,423,544 ))
```

This is what I'm looking for:

```
dfCleaned <- data.frame(StandarTime =  c("2017-08-25 10:15",
                                     "2017-08-25 12:15",
                                     "2017-08-25 10:15" ),
                    AchievedTime =  c("2017-08-25 13:14 PDT",
                                      "2017-08-25 7:03 PDT",
                                      "2017-08-25 9:04 PDT" ))
```

I'm not sure how to best approach this problem.

Comment: Help me out: Map `c(615,735,615 )` to `c("2017-08-25 10:15",
                                     "2017-08-25 12:15",
                                     "2017-08-25 10:15" )` please. I get the addition of `2017-08-25`.

Comment: The Excel data has those values, but I need to convert them to times in R.  I was dividing those numbers by 60 to get the 'minutes' but I needed to convert that a field in POSIXct  class in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the values are but in case these are seconds you can use:

```
> dfOrig$StandarTime <- ISOdate(2017, 8, 25, hour = 0) + dfOrig$StandarTime
> dfOrig$AchievedTime <- ISOdate(2017, 8, 25, hour = 0) + dfOrig$AchievedTime
> dfOrig
          StandarTime        AchievedTime
1 2017-08-25 00:10:15 2017-08-25 00:13:14
2 2017-08-25 00:12:15 2017-08-25 00:07:03
3 2017-08-25 00:10:15 2017-08-25 00:09:04
```

`ISOdate(2017, 8, 25, hour = 0)` sets the start time, then you can add a value in seconds. You can also specify a time zone using `tz = ""`